# Getting HttpRequest from SignalR Hub

Tags: signalr, httprequest

I have a web site with SignalR Hub (and jQuery code at the client for connecting).
I need to get the HttpRequest object for authentication.

The signalR have a Context.Request object(which is Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Owin.ServerRequest) but I can't find the way to convert it into an HttpRequest.

Does any one have an idea how to perform that?

Edit:
As it turns out, you can always go to HttpContext.Current and use the Request/Response object. But be careful, Not all reqular operations are supported, some of them will result in ThreadAborted Exception